# Python pdb - writing consol command in script

Tags: python, debugging, console, pdb

The problem is I have a pytest file where I want to investigate the values of the the code. I have a few breakpoints:

```
ar = typing.cast(Array, Coil) 
breakpoint()         
if sector_name:
    ar.data["Alias"] = ar.asset_class + " - " + sector_name
    breakpoint() 
cols_exist = []
```

and now whenever I want the check the value of the variable I need to go to the consol and run "**pp variable**" and then "**n**" and again "**pp next_variable**" in the consol.

I wonder if it is possible(I believe it should be but can't find it), to type in a script something like:

```
breakpoint().run("pp variable")
```

And  run commands automatically whenever the new breakpoint appears. That would be very helpful and should be easy to implement so I hope there is something like that.

PS. My test folder is in the separate folder than the main package so I run PyTest from the main project folder(allowing importing the testing pyfiles) - just mentioning it just in case, as I saw people were runing pytest scripts for the specyfic files, and it can make a difference.

Cheers !